# What language can I use to write a program to delete music files (.mp3) with a certain rating?

Tags: file, mp3, editing

I want to prune my music library. Which contains around 2k songs. It's easier for me to rate a song having heard it than to actively find it and delete it manually.

Is it possible to write a program that looks for songs within a folder that have particular ratings, title, artists, etc. and deletes (or put them into a folder of its own to be deleted)? I've never written a program that manipulates files before. What should I start learning?

Comment: The people that are downvoting this question should speak up and maybe say that http://programmers.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask this question?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: personally, I feel the distinction is quite ridiculous.. but yeah: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange btw, when you feel your question has been answered you should accept one of the answers by clicking its big green tick.

Comment: This question belongs to programers. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are referring to what sort of libraries are available in programming languages.

Specifically, you'll need to be using a language which has a library available to access and manipulate files and directories on your local machine, and you'll need a library to access the metadata format for your mp3 files.

Make sure that you know how the metadata for your mp3 files is being recorded (i.e. what format is being used).

I would have thought most commonplace programming languages would have these available. So, the question you need to investigate is, which language would I prefer to use and why?

Answer (score 0):

Python is very [beginner-friendly](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) and can easily [read/write files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

If the ratings etc. part of the file (i.e. ID3 metadata) you might need a [library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsefulModules#ID3_Handling) or maybe even better; follow [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) that discusses this in chapter 5.